# Parameters in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying to develop a report in SQL Server Reporting Services using parameters.

I have no problem creating the parameters and running the reports, but I always have to select an item from each of the parameters to make it run. Can I have the option to leave one of the parameters blank and still have the report run? Right now when I hit 'view report', I always get the error that I must make a selection to continue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check off the **Allow blank value** checkbox for the parameter(s) you want to allow a blank value for.

1. Right click anywhere outside the report on the **Layout** tab
2. Select **Report Parameters**
3. Select the parameter you want to allow blank values for
4. Check off the **Allow blank value** checkbox

Repeat as needed for each parameter.

Comment: I have tried this with no luck. I have also tried 'allow null value' and every combination of both.

Comment: How are you testing?  If from the server, are you sure you're deploying before testing?

Comment: I have not deployed the report. I am using the preview tab to test the report.

Comment: I'm testing in SSRS 2005 - the behaviour works as expected for me in the Preview tab. If a parameter has "allow blank" checked off, I don't get prompted if I left it blank and vice versa.

Comment: Ok, so why do you think I am getting prompted? I am obviously missing something? Could it have something to do with my SQL Query?

Comment: IME, it has nothing to do with the query - the values don't get to it if the View Report validation doesn't let you through.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is that not all of your parameters are set to allow blanks, but dates & drop downs don't support blank values.

Comment: That could be my problem. I am trying to get a blank value from a drop down list. I have tried it with a text box and it works, but that does not solve my problem. What is the solution for a drop down list?

Comment: You can set a default value in the Report Parameters, Default values section (bottom righthand corner).  Select the **Non-queried** radio button, and provide the value (**not** the label value).  I've found "=[value]" is what works when the report is deployed, but the Preview tab has preferred to not have the "=" portion sometimes for me.

Comment: This does not help. It will only accept a default value that is already in the Drop Down List. If it doesn't exist in the list, it will ask me to make a selection and that defeats what I am trying to accomplish. I am thinking I might have to assign a blank record to the start of my Data Set through the query and then set that to my Default value.

Comment: Yes, the default value has to exist in the drop down list of values.